# JavaFX: Menubar width across entire frame

Tags: css, javafx, fxml, menubar

I'm using NetBeans and SceneBuilder to make a JavaFX GUI. My question is among the three files (the FXML, the controller, and the java file) what do I need to do to make the width of my menubar expand when the user expands the stage (or anchor pane, please also educate me on the proper term)?

Thanks!
~Bricks

Comment: This question needs more input, such as what is the **root layout** that you are using. Also, I think this can be handled in FMXL, so if you written one which doesn't work, please add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong, thanks to ItachiUchiha's comment. I was originally using `AnchorPane` as my root layout but switched to `HBox` so that I could use the `hgrow` property.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<HBox>
  <children>
    <MenuBar HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
      <menus>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
      </menus>
    </MenuBar>
  </children>
</HBox>
```

Comment: You can of course do something similar with `VBox` and `vgrow`.